# Close read file and open again required in order to write search result string to output file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code:

```
import fileinput, os, glob, re

# Find text file to search in. Open.
filename = str(glob.glob('*.txt'))[2:][:-2]
print("found " + filename + ", opening...")
f = open(filename, 'r')

# Create output csv write total found occurrences of search string after name of search string 
with open(filename[:-4] + 'output.csv','w') as output:    
    output.write("------------Group 1----------\n")
    output.write(("String 1,") + str((len(re.findall(r's5 .*w249 w1025 w301 w1026 .*',f.read())))) +"\n")
    output.write(("String 1 reverse,") + str((len(re.findall(r's5 .*w1026 w301 w1025 w249 .*',f.read())))) +"\n")

# close and finish
f.close
output.close
```

It successfully finds the first string and writes the total count to the output file, but it writes zero finds for 'String 1 reverse', even though it should find 1000's.

It works if I insert this between searching for String 1 and String 1 reverse:

```
f.close
f = open(filename, 'r')
```

i.e. I close the read file and then open it again.

I don't want to have to add this after each search line, what's going on? Is it something to do with caching the open file or cache in regex?

Thanks

Comment: `f.close()` not `f.close`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have samples to test your example, but I suspect that the issue comes from:

```
 output.write(("String 1,") + str((len(re.findall(r's5 .*w249 w1025 w301 w1026 .*',f.read())))) +"\n")
 output.write(("String 1 reverse,") + str((len(re.findall(r's5 .*w1026 w301 w1025 w249 .*',f.read())))) +"\n")
```

You are doing `f.read()` two times, which means that the entire file is read, and the cursor is then set at the end of the file. The second `f.read()` will return an empty string, because there is no more data to read.

You have to remember that reading a file means that the reading cursor (the position attached to the file descriptor) will change of `+n` bytes after reading `n` bytes. With no arguments `f.read()` will read for the entire file size bytes, and leave the cursor at end of file.

You have two solutions:

1. Store the file content in a variable (Eg: `content = f.read()`) and perform your searches on that variable.
2. Use the file seek features:

> To change the file object’s position, use f.seek(offset, from_what). The position is computed from adding offset to a reference point; the reference point is selected by the from_what argument. A from_what value of 0 measures from the beginning of the file, 1 uses the current file position, and 2 uses the end of the file as the reference point. from_what can be omitted and defaults to 0, using the beginning of the file as the reference point.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

The first solution is actually recommended: you don't need to read the file more than once, and seeking features are mostly used for large file operations.

Here is a fixed version of your code following that recommendation:

```
import fileinput, os, glob, re

# Find text file to search in. Open.
filename = str(glob.glob('*.txt'))[2:][:-2]
print("found " + filename + ", opening...")
content = open(filename, 'r').read()

# Create output csv write total found occurrences of search string after name of search string 
with open(filename[:-4] + 'output.csv','w') as output:    
    output.write("------------Group 1----------\n")
    output.write(("String 1,") + str((len(re.findall(r's5 .*w249 w1025 w301 w1026 .*',content)))) +"\n")
    output.write(("String 1 reverse,") + str((len(re.findall(r's5 .*w1026 w301 w1025 w249 .*',content)))) +"\n")
```

*Optimization: note that you don't need to `close()` on variables now, as you keep no reference of the file instances.*

Answer (score 1):

Once you do a `file.read()`, the entire file is read and the pointer is at the end of the file; which is why the second line doesn't return any results.

You need to read the contents first, then run your analysis:

```
print("found " + filename + ", opening...")
f = open(filename, 'r')
contents = f.read()
f.close()  # -- note f.close() not f.close

results_a = re.findall(r's5 .*w249 w1025 w301 w1026 .*',contents)
results_b = re.findall(r's5 .*w1026 w301 w1025 w249 .*',contents)

with open(filename[:-4] + 'output.csv','w') as output:    
    output.write("------------Group 1----------\n")
    output.write("String 1 {}\n".format(len(results_a)))
    output.write("String 1 reverse, {}\n".format(len(results_b)))
```

You don't need `output.close` (it didn't do anything in the first place), as the with statement automatically will close the file.

If you want to repeat this operation for all the files that match your pattern:

```
import glob
import re
import os

BASE_DIR = '/full/path/to/file/directory'

for file in glob.iglob(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '*.txt')):
  with open(file) as f:
     contents = f.read()
     filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))[0]
     results_a = re.findall(r's5 .*w249 w1025 w301 w1026 .*',contents)
     results_b = re.findall(r's5 .*w1026 w301 w1025 w249 .*',contents)
     with open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '{}output.csv'.format(filename), 'w') as output:
        output.write("------------Group 1----------\n")
        output.write("String 1 {}\n".format(len(results_a)))
        output.write("String 1 reverse, {}\n".format(len(results_b)))
```